# Grouping variables and sapply function.

Tags: r

This relates to a recent post about calculating standard error using a function. The following code works. It is a function to pass outcome variable names in a wide dataframe into a function in order to calculate SE for eventual adding as error bars on a ggplot2 bar graph.

First create data

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"), 4), score1 = runif(16, 0, 10), score2 = runif(16, 3, 7))
```

then write the function. The 'condGroup' specifies the level of the independent variable 'group' and 'colDV' is the column name of the outcome variable of interest.

```
groupSEs <- function (condGroup, colDV) {
  SE <- sd(df[df$group == condGroup, colDV])/sqrt(nrow(df[df$group == condGroup,]))
  return(SE)
}
```

Next create a vector of all the level names within the group variable

```
groupSubset <- c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4")
```

Then pass this vector into a sapply using the function we created earlier

```
SE <- sapply(groupSubset, function(x) groupSEs(x, "score1"))
```

When we call it

```
SE
```

We get this output

```
group1   group2   group3   group4 
1.237912 1.733068 1.584986 1.533830
```

So that works. However I also have several independent grouping variables in  my dataset and it would be nice to calculate SEs based on levels within these.

So once again we create data but this time with the addition of another grouping variable.

```
set.seed(1)

df2 <- data.frame(groupIV1 = factor(rep(c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"), 4)),
                 groupIV2 = factor(rep(c("groupA", "groupB", "groupC", "groupD"), 4)),
                 score1 = runif(16, 0, 10),
                 score2 = runif(16, 3, 7))
```

This time the function we write above will have an additional argument, the name of the grouping variable 'IVGroup'

```
groupSEs <- function (condGroup, IVGroup, colDV) {
  SE <- sd(df2[df2$IVGroup == condGroup, colDV])/sqrt(nrow(df2[df2$IVGroup == condGroup,]))
  return(SE)
}
```

Now we create the vectors of level names

```
groupSubset <- c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4")
groupSubset2 <- c("groupA", "groupB", "groupC", "groupD")
```

We can pass either of these into the sapply function. I chose the second

```
SE2 <- sapply(groupSubset2, function(x) groupSEs(x, "groupIV2", "score1"))
```

Now when I call it

```
SE
```

I get this

```
groupA groupB groupC groupD 
    NA     NA     NA     NA
```

so why can't I use that extra argument in the second example?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do - but have you looked into tapply?

Comment: You are using the wrong variable. Try simply this and you will see: `df2$IVGroup == condGroup`. Changing it to `df2$groupIV2` should fix your problem I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `IVGroup` variable contains the name of the column stored as a string, so you can't use `$` to adress it : you can `[, "colName"]` instead so your function would be:

```
groupSEs <- function (condGroup, IVGroup, colDV) {
        SE <- sd(df2[df2[,IVGroup] == condGroup, colDV])/sqrt(nrow(df2[df2[,IVGroup] == condGroup,]))
        return(SE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HubertL that worked. I had a feeling it would be something to do with the $. I would give you the +1 but I don't have enough reputation points to do that yet.